# Backup and restore DB to remote DB cause blank page

Tags: 8, database

i'm new to drupal 8, i'm trying to backup and restore localhost db to remote db, but when i open home page, it just display a blank page (with source code).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr" prefix="content: http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/  dc: http://purl.org/dc/terms/  foaf: http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/  og: http://ogp.me/ns#  rdfs: http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#  schema: http://schema.org/  sioc: http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#  sioct: http://rdfs.org/sioc/types#  skos: http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#  xsd: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema# ">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="Generator" content="Drupal 8 (https://www.drupal.org)" />
<meta name="MobileOptimized" content="width" />
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/core/misc/favicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />

    <title>Home | plant testing site</title>
    <style media="all">
@import url("/core/assets/vendor/normalize-css/normalize.css?odbvth");
@import url("/core/themes/stable/css/system/components/ajax-progress.module.css?odbvth");
@import url("/core/themes/stable/css/system/components/align.module.css?odbvth");
@import url("/core/themes/stable/css/system/components/autocomplete-loading.module.css?odbvth");
@import url("/core/themes/stable/css/system/components/fieldgroup.module.css?odbvth");
@import url("/core/themes/stable/css/system/components/container-inline.module.css?odbvth");
@import url("/core/themes/stable/css/system/components/clearfix.module.css?odbvth");
@import url("/core/themes/stable/css/system/components/details.module.css?odbvth");
@import url("/core/themes/stable/css/system/components/hidden.module.css?odbvth");
@import url("/core/themes/stable/css/system/components/item-list.module.css?odbvth");
@import url("/core/themes/stable/css/system/components/js.module.css?odbvth");
@import url("/core/themes/stable/css/system/components/nowrap.module.css?odbvth");
@import url("/core/themes/stable/css/system/components/position-container.module.css?odbvth");
@import url("/core/themes/stable/css/system/components/progress.module.css?odbvth");
@import url("/core/themes/stable/css/system/components/reset-appearance.module.css?odbvth");
@import url("/core/themes/stable/css/system/components/resize.module.css?odbvth");
@import url("/core/themes/stable/css/system/components/sticky-header.module.css?odbvth");
@import url("/core/themes/stable/css/system/components/tabledrag.module.css?odbvth");
@import url("/core/themes/stable/css/system/components/tablesort.module.css?odbvth");
@import url("/core/themes/stable/css/system/components/tree-child.module.css?odbvth");
</style>
<style media="all">
@import url("/themes/bootstrap_business/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css?odbvth");
@import url("/themes/bootstrap_business/css/base/style.css?odbvth");
@import url("/themes/bootstrap_business/css/base/colors.css?odbvth");
@import url("/themes/bootstrap_business/css/base/local.css?odbvth");
@import url("/core/themes/classy/css/components/action-links.css?odbvth");
@import url("/core/themes/classy/css/components/breadcrumb.css?odbvth");
@import url("/core/themes/classy/css/components/button.css?odbvth");
@import url("/core/themes/classy/css/components/collapse-processed.css?odbvth");
@import url("/core/themes/classy/css/components/container-inline.css?odbvth");
@import url("/core/themes/classy/css/components/details.css?odbvth");
@import url("/core/themes/classy/css/components/exposed-filters.css?odbvth");
@import url("/core/themes/classy/css/components/field.css?odbvth");
@import url("/core/themes/classy/css/components/form.css?odbvth");
@import url("/core/themes/classy/css/components/icons.css?odbvth");
@import url("/core/themes/classy/css/components/inline-form.css?odbvth");
@import url("/core/themes/classy/css/components/item-list.css?odbvth");
@import url("/core/themes/classy/css/components/link.css?odbvth");
@import url("/core/themes/classy/css/components/links.css?odbvth");
@import url("/core/themes/classy/css/components/menu.css?odbvth");
@import url("/core/themes/classy/css/components/more-link.css?odbvth");
@import url("/core/themes/classy/css/components/pager.css?odbvth");
@import url("/core/themes/classy/css/components/tabledrag.css?odbvth");
@import url("/core/themes/classy/css/components/tableselect.css?odbvth");
@import url("/core/themes/classy/css/components/tablesort.css?odbvth");
@import url("/core/themes/classy/css/components/tabs.css?odbvth");
@import url("/core/themes/classy/css/components/textarea.css?odbvth");
@import url("/core/themes/classy/css/components/ui-dialog.css?odbvth");
@import url("/themes/bootstrap_business/css/components/primary-menu.css?odbvth");
@import url("/themes/bootstrap_business/css/components/to-top.css?odbvth");
</style>


<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<script src="/core/assets/vendor/html5shiv/html5shiv.min.js?v=3.7.3"></script>
<![endif]-->

  </head>
  <body class="path-frontpage">
        <a href="#main-content" class="visually-hidden focusable skip-link">
      Skip to main content
    </a>



    <script src="/core/assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js?v=2.1.4"></script>
<script src="/themes/bootstrap_business/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?v=8.1.8"></script>
<script src="/themes/bootstrap_business/js/custom/toggle.js?v=8.1.8"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

anyone know what is the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: We need much more information. Does the <head> portion match what you're expecting? It appears that Drupal has a MySQL connection and is working. Who is your remote hosting service? How are you performing your backup and restore? Do you have shell access on your remote server? Do you have drush installed?

Comment: how to install drush easily? seems better than run sql in db

Comment: http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/ in short, I use composer to install drush.

Comment: "seems better?" How do you ensure you've respected all the various data process rules as it relates to Drupal storage, data integrity and security, based on raw sql statements? Resist the urge, seriously.

Answer (score 0):

run this to clear cache

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `cache_bootstrap`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cache_config`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cache_container`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cache_data`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cache_default`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cache_discovery`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cache_dynamic_page_cache`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cache_entity`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cache_menu`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cache_render`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cache_toolbar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cachetags`;
```

Comment: or `drush cr` for a proper cache-clearing. I avoid directly fiddling with the tables.